# How can I see that $\Bbb F_{p^2}(t)$ is a separable extension of $\Bbb F_p(t)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

I am given 2 examples to see that a imperfect field can have both separable and inseparable extensions.

I am told that  $\Bbb F_{p^2}(t)$ is a separable extension of $\Bbb F_p(t)$, where  $\Bbb F_p(t)$ is imperfect.

But how can I see that fact that $\Bbb F_{p^2}(t)$ is a seperable extension? May I please ask for a proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: How do you get the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ from the field $\mathbb{F}_p$? The addition of the transcendent variable $t$ does not change things much.

Second hint: How does separability relate to minimal polynomials?

Comment: Is it the fact that $[\Bbb F_{p^2}:\Bbb F_p]=2$ so if we write $\Bbb F_{p^2}=\Bbb F_p(\alpha)$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is of degree 2. By the quadratic formula, once we have one root $\alpha\in\Bbb F_p(\alpha)$, the other root of the polynomial is also in $\Bbb F_p(\alpha)$. So the minimal polynomial of the $\alpha$ we adjoint to $\Bbb F_p$ splitts in $\Bbb F_{p^2}$?

Comment: @PropositionX You are close, but you have not mentioned separability yet. What about the minimal polynomial tells you about separability?

Comment: I thought for  while and I am worring about how to proceed. I think to conclude that it has no multiple roots, I need to conclude that the minimal polynomial is not of form $(x-\alpha)^2$ in its splitting field $\Bbb F_p(\alpha)$.May I please ask is that correct? What to do to conclude it?

Comment: @PropositionX Yes, you are correct. For fields of characteristic $p>2$, then you are essentially adjoining the square root of an element, and in that case the minimal polynomial is $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x+\alpha)$. In characteristic $2$ it is a little bit more subtle, but it turns out that $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ is the minimal polynomial which works and is separable.

Comment: @user1952009 I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{q^2} = \mathbb{F}_q(\zeta_{q+1})$ should always work

Comment: @user1952009 What is $\zeta_{q+1}$?

Comment: Get it! And may I please ask once I conclude that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is seperable, how can prove that every element in $\Bbb F_{p^2}(t)$ has a separable minimal polynomial?

Comment: @PropositionX That fact follows from a very important theorem regarding separable extensions. See here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/separable1.pdf Theorem 3.5

Comment: (primitive root of unity, in particular $\zeta_3$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$) Since $[\mathbb{F}_{p^2}(t):\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)] = 2$ you are searching for a minimal polynomial of degree $2$. In general, looking at the Galois group of  $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}(t)/\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ can be a good idea.

Comment: @user1952009 This does not work in general; a primitive $6$th root of unity over $\mathbb{F}_5$ has degree 4.

Comment: @ThomasGrubb There is a primitive $6$th root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{25}^\times$ so it should be of degree $2$

Comment: @PropositionX  The minimal polynomial of $\frac{\sum_{n=0}^d  a_n t^n}{\sum_{n=0}^c b_n t^n} \in \mathbb{F}_{p^k}(t)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ is (or divides) $\prod_{\sigma \in G} (X-\frac{\sum_{n=0}^d  \sigma(a_n) t^n}{\sum_{n=0}^c \sigma(b_n) t^n})$ where $G = Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^k}/\mathbb{F}_{p})$ (because $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ is the fixed field of $G$)

Comment: @user1952009 Wow, it looks quite complicated to show all the steps of proving such a polynomial is separable... Is there some useful trick to prove that?

Comment: By the important theorem quoted by Thomas : $\alpha$ generates $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}/\mathbb{F}_{p}$ as well as $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}(t)/\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ and it is obviously separable since its minimal polynomial stays the same in the transcendental extension

Comment: @ThomasGrubb You can see that $[\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta_{p+1}):\mathbb{F}_p] = 2$ from $Frob(\zeta_{p+1}) = \zeta_{p+1}^p, Frob^2(\zeta_{p+1})=\zeta_{p+1}^{p^2} = \zeta_{p+1}$